# go.mod: force use specific version for indirect dependency

Tags: go, dependency-management

Say my direct dependency `A` depends on package `B v1.0`. `B v1.0` is not listed in `go.mod` but its checksum exists in `go.sum`

Is there a way to force my project to use `B v1.1`? What if package `B` is a few levels down in the dependency graph?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `go get B@v1.1` It will then appear in `go.mod` suffixed with a comment of `// indirect`

Comment: I did that and ran ```go mod graph | grep B```. I still see ```B v1.0``` being used in the dependency tree

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, go.mod can have indirect dependencies as following:

```
module test

go 1.16

require (
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
    github.com/kr/pretty v0.1.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210415231046-e915ea6b2b7d // indirect
)
```

The above is a go.mod from one of my projects. Mind that the `// indirect` is not a manual comment.

To lock a dependency version, just update go.mod or simply do a `go get B@1.1`

Comment: After doing ```go get B@0.2``` I ran ```mod graph | grep B```. But I still see ```B v0.1``` being used in the dependency tree? ```B``` is a dependency several layers down the dependency tree.

Comment: Lower versions of ```B``` are still in ```go.sum``` so I assume those versions are still being used.